# iOS 8 UIImagePickerController has black preview in Landscape mode

Tags: camera, ios8, uiimagepickercontroller, landscape, preview

I am developing app for iPad, in Landscape mode during taking a snapshot from camera a black preview appears.While , UIImagePickerController works properly for Portrait mode.Thanks in advance.

this is my piece of code -

```
-(UIImagePickerController *)imagePicker{
if(!imagePicker){
    imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
}
return imagePicker;
}


[self presentViewController:self.imagePicker animated:YES completion:^{ }];
```

PS: Anybody knows about, "Contacts" default app of iOS device having this feature rotation of camera controls with respect to device orientation.Here, Camera preview looks fine for all orientation.Anybody knows its implementation.

Answer (score -1):

if you are using Autolayout then you first Check for the co-ordinates and size of corresponding preview(UIimageview).